# Volume of a container with unknown side and known surface area

Tags: algebra-precalculus, volume

We have to make a closed container.  All side surfaces (walls, ceiling and bottom) must be rectangles and stand perpendicular to each other. One of the sides should be $3 \,m$ long.  The surface area of ​​the container shall be $32 \,m^2$. Let one of the other two sides be $x$ meters long. Show that the volume is given by the formula: $$V = \frac{48x-9x^2}{x + 3}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What are the surface area and volume of a rectangular prism with sides 3, x, and y?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I think the volume is given by 3xy. Surface area is given in the question, 32. I have no idea what the formula for the surface area would be.

Comment: The surface area would be 6x + 6y + 2xy?

Comment: Figured it out. y = (16-3x)/(3+x) considering the equation above.

Comment: Where did you get this formula?

Answer (score 0):

Unless we let $x=y$ the formula does not have enough information to identify volume.  If, however, we let $x=y$, then we can show that the formula works, with the restriction that $x=-8$ or $x=2$.

$$
2(3\cdot x)+2(3\cdot y) + 2(x\cdot y) = 32 \\
2 x y + 6 x + 6 y = 32\\
x = \dfrac{16 - 3 y}{y + 3},
y=x\implies x,y\in\big\{-8,2\big\}\\
$$

\begin{align*}
x=y\in\big\{-8,2\big\}\implies V=3\cdot (-8)^2=192\\
V = 3\cdot (2)^2=12
\end{align*}

$$
V = \frac{48x-9x^2}{x + 3}, x=-8 \implies V=192\\
V = \frac{48x-9x^2}{x + 3}, x=2 \implies V=12
$$